# Clipboard: Copy and receive array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, clipboard

In a Winform application I have an array of this format:

float[][,]

I need to copy it via the clipboard to another Winform app.
How could I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: What should it look like when it gets there? If you write both apps, perhaps  consider an alternative form of IPC

Comment: It should look the same. Since the data is just floats, I thought the clipboard would just be the simplest way to do it, isn't it?

Comment: And wipe out the user's copied data in the process? Plenty of other options https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/local-machine-interprocess-communication-with-net - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5162436/Simple-SignalR-Server-and-Client-Applications-Demo - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=net-5.0 etc

Comment: I am aware that there are plenty other ways, most of them crazy complex. But I prefer the clipboard due to its simplicity. Is this so ridiculous?

Comment: *Is this so ridiculous?* - In my view, yes. If you're going to do that you might as well just write to a file and not trash the user's clipboard.. Writing a file is a single line, using a filesystemwatcher to pick up the change and read the file in is a single line too.. It's terrible, but if you're desperate to save on the [~5 lines of code](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/804770/implementing-signalr-in-desktop-applications) it'll take to run a signalR server, and ~5 lines to create a client..

Comment: I'm also curious, if the Clipboard route is so simple, why is there a need to even ask a question about it? Just bash a data object onto it and off again at the other side..

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: Using the [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard?view=net-5.0) is simple.

Use `Clipboard.SetData("CustomDataName", nonStandardData);` to put your custom data on the clipboard and use `var clipboardData = (float[][,])Clipboard.GetData("CustomDataName");` to get your custom data off the clipboard. You should check if the data is available on the clipboard using `Clipboard.ContainsData("CustomDataName")`

> Note: By default the Windows clipboard only contains **one** entry at
> a time be it an "image", "text" or "custom data". By putting your
> custom data on the clipboard the previous data contained on the
> clipboard will be gone.

The clipboard is best used for sharing more universal data between
unrelated programs, such as an image which can be pasted into a web browser or image editor. A grid of csv values which can be pasted into different data capturing and spreadsheet programs. `float[][,]` on the other hand has no real meaning other than to your software.

**Long Answer** (Here is an example):

```
    // A Format/"Type" name for your clipboard data
    static readonly string JOE_SOAP_DATA_V1 = 
        "JOE_SOAP_DATA_V1 {F1193E97-0B29-4ACD-935C-835A8EDFBB9D}";

    // Some dummy data used to demonstrate
    private readonly float[][,] JoeSoapData = new float[3][,]
    {
        new float[,]{{54,90},{34,56}},
        new float[,]
        {
            {
                // random values to create some variation
                // will be different each time program is started
                (float)new Random().NextDouble() * 2, 
                (float)new Random().NextDouble() * 6  
            },
            {
                (float)new Random().NextDouble() * 4,
                (float)new Random().NextDouble() * 7
            },
            {
                (float)new Random().NextDouble() * 4,
                (float)new Random().NextDouble() * 7
            }
        },
        new float[,]{{54,90},{34,56}}
    };

    private string JoeSoapDataToString(float[][,] data)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var x in data)
        {
            foreach (var y in x)
                sb.Append(y).Append(", ");
            sb.Append('\n');
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private void BtnCopyToClipboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // On button click add the dummy data to the clipboard
        Clipboard.SetData(JOE_SOAP_DATA_V1, JoeSoapData);
    }

    private void BtnPasteFromClipboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Check if the clipboard contains our unique Format and notify the user if it does not
        if (!Clipboard.ContainsData(JOE_SOAP_DATA_V1))
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"No {nameof(JOE_SOAP_DATA_V1)} clipboard data found :(");
            return;
        }

        // extract the clipboard data and show the user
        var clipboardData = (float[][,])Clipboard.GetData(JOE_SOAP_DATA_V1);

        // show the copied data
        LblFromClipboard.Text = "Data from clipboard\n" + JoeSoapDataToString(clipboardData);
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LblDataToCopy.Text = "Data that will be copied to the clipboard\n"
        + JoeSoapDataToString(JoeSoapData);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for! Big time save.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AddClipboardFormatListener](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.AddClipboardFormatListener) (for listening the clipboard update message) combined with [Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard) class to copy the data.

Receiver app:

```
public partial class ReceiverAppMainForm : Form
{
    public ReceiverAppMainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        ClipboardWrapper.AddClipboardFormatListener(Handle);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        ClipboardWrapper.RemoveClipboardFormatListener(Handle);
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == ClipboardWrapper.WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE)
        {
            var data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

            if (data != null && data.GetDataPresent("clipboard-demoapp-data"))
            {
                var array = (float[][,])data.GetData("clipboard-demoapp-data");
                // TODO: use the shared data
            }
        }
    }

    internal static class ClipboardWrapper
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool RemoveClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);

        internal const int WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE = 0x031D;
    }
}
```

Sender app:

```
public partial class SenderAppMainForm : Form
{

   // ... ignored for brevity

    private static void CopyAppDataToClipboard(float[][,] data)
    {
        // variant #1 (to avoid duplication)
        var dataObject = new DataObject();
        dataObject.SetData("clipboard-demoapp-data", data);
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject, false, 10, 100);

        // variant #2 (the event is sending twice on my computer running Win10)
        //Clipboard.SetData("cliboard-demoapp-data", data);
    }
}
```